# how to know the behavior of MariaDB engine

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization, groupwise-maximum

I am new to MySQL/MariaDB.

I am comparing performance of a Stored Procedure in both MS SQL and MariaDB and found the performance of MariaDB to be slower than MS SQL. I found that the same query is taking more time in MariaDB than MSSQL. In fact i had to add an index on temporary table in the stored procedure which was not required in MS SQL. Why this type of result.
How and where can i dig more into the behavior of MariadB engine like execution plan(detailed). Which performance monitoring tool(open source) will help me in handling slow queries as well as optimization other than slow query log.

How can i use EXPLAIN for below code
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_ABC AS SELECT * from tbl_ABC

Regards,
Saumik Vora

Comment: Use the `EXPLAIN` command to see the execution plan.

Comment: *How can i use EXPLAIN for below code* What do you want to obtain as execution plan for CREATE TABLE??? look at the execution plan for SELECT part of the query (which makes no sense for shown query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways to get execution plan info (in order of detail):

- `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`
- `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`
- Turn on the "Optimizer trace".

`EXPLAIN` works on some queries other than `SELECT`.  If it does not work for your `CREATE`, simply apply it to just the `SELECT`.  (In either case, *that* query will have a very trivial Explain.)

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the most important setting in MariaDB; it is about 70% of available RAM?

MySQL/MariaDB will auto-generate indexes derived tables (`FROM ( SELECT ... )`) in some cases; but not on temp tables.

There are several techniques for avoiding the need for explicit (`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...`) temp tables; would you care to show us the query; we may have some tips.

Because of many structural differences between MSSql and MariaDB, there are likely to be some queries that run faster or slower in each.

Provide us with one of your queries that is slower in MariaDB; we may be able to speed it up.

Comment: The table tbl_ABC contains around 6000000 records. All the columns of that table is going to be referred. just copying the data into temp table takes 36 seconds. Now this temp table contains Order Details & we need to refer latest state of each order. So another query which takes 30 second is as `CREATE Temporary Table DPOD AS Select MAX(SerialNo),OrderNo from tmp_DEF a Inner join tmp_ABC b on a.OrderNo=b.OrderNo and b.RefNo=0 group by b.OrderNo`.  note tmp_DEF contains around 1000k records. These temp table are ref in final query joined with other tables. O/P comes out in 16 sec

Comment: Using temp tables instead of combining the queries -- this leads to extra work.  See the tag I added.

Comment: thanks Rick. Strange removing Temp tables did improve the performance. However i still had to maintain that temp table with group wise max query. Degrades the performance if i kept that in final select. Thanks once again for the help